# Why index name always appears in the parquet file created with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parquet, fastparquet

I am trying to create a parquet using pandas dataframe, and even though I delete the index of the file, it is still appearing when I am re-reading the parquet file. Can anyone help me with this? I want index.name to be set as **None**.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'key': 1}, index=[0])
>>> df
  key
0    1
>>> df.to_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df
     key
index     
0        1
>>> del df.index.name
>>> df
     key
0    1
>>> df.to_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df
     key
index     
0        1
```

Comment: Is this using fastparquet or pyarrow as the Parquet backend?

Comment: Using fastparquet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected using pyarrow:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'key': 1}, index=[0])
>>> df.to_parquet('test.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
>>> df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> del df.index.name
>>> df
   key
0    1
>>> df.to_parquet('test.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
>>> df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df
       key
index     
0        1 ---> INDEX NAME APPEARS EVEN AFTER DELETING USING fastparquet
>>> del df.index.name
>>> df.to_parquet('test.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
>>> df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df
   key
0    1 --> INDEX NAME IS NONE WHEN CONVERSION IS DONE WITH pyarrow
```

Answer (score 4):

Hey this works with **pyarrow** with the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': 1}, index=[0])
df.to_parquet('test.parquet', engine='pyarrow', index=False)
df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
df.head()
```

As @alexopoulos7 mentioned in the [to_parquet documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) it states you can use the "*index*" argument as a parameter. It seems to work, perhaps because I'm explicitly stating the `engine='pyarrow'`

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing with both libraries [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/index.html) and [fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write), trying to write a parquet file without preserving indexes since I need those data to be read from redshift as an external table.

For me what it worked was for library **fastparquet**

```
df.to_parquet(destination_file, engine='fastparquet', compression='gzip', write_index=False)
```

If you try to follow the [**to_parquet** official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) you will see that it mentions parameter "*index*" but this throws an error if this argument does not exist in the used engine. Currently, I have found that only fastparquet has such an option and in named "*write_index*"